# Add class to list item in Orchard pager list

Tags: orchardcms

I need to add a class to the `li` tag in an orchard pager list.

I can see that the shape is built in CoreShapes.cs, and classes are being added to the first and last items. I don't want to edit Orchard source code and add `itemTag.AddCssClass("my-class")`.

I can add an alternate for `List`, but this overrides lists on the whole site. ShapeTracing doesn't show any other alternates.

I have been debugging with Pager.cshtml and associated alternates .Last, .Link etc., but I can't get to the `li` between the link and `ul`.

I have read this [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/overriding-the-pager-rendering-in-orchard), but this only coves the stuff inside the `li`.
I have read this [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template), but this assumes I have `Model.ContentItems`.

There are similar questions on SO, but they only cover content items which actually have alternates.

Ideally I want to do something like add `List.Pager.cshtml` and in there do;

```
<li class="my-class">
    @Display(Model)
</li>
```

Comment: If you're able to write a sufficient `Match` rule in your `placement.info` you could [add an alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/#alternate) from there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a alternate for the list shape is the way to go i think.

1) Add an [alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes/) for your specific list like `MyList.cshtml`

2) Borrow some code from `Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/Menu.cshtml` and add the following lines to `MyList.cshtml`:

```
var items = (IList<dynamic>)Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(Model.Items);

if (items.Any()) {
  items[%YourItem%].Classes.Add("my-class");
}

...

@DisplayChildren(Model)
```